# Augmented Reality object motion tracking (without markers)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, augmented-reality

Is there any AS3 library that will allow you to detect and track motion of an object via webcam without any marker or image. For example I want to build a game where you could play with ball just using your hand movements. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't use any library for that. There is many native ways to do that. For example you can write something like that

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,handleMotion);

public function handleMotion(e:Event):void
{
    if (ball.x != oldBallX || ball.y != oldBallY)
    {
    //Do something
    }    
}
```

or override a setter of x and y property of ball class and put a there a your tracking function. Third way is just put your tracking function into callbacks which handle user input.

Comment: Apparently I haven't been specific enough, I meant how can you do that with augmented reality.

Comment: I am sorry. I missed the word "webcam" when i's reading your question. Talking about webcams and detection movement throught them i may to suggest  you a calculate difference between images which apps are getting from camera.